# Python: how to group pandas Data Frame in a certain time window?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe `df` containing data of different trips from an origin `X` to a destination `Y` with starting time `T`. I want to count trips between `X` and `Y` in a certain time windows, let say `15 min`. So,

```
df:
X Y           T
1 2 2015-12-30 22:30:00.0
1 2 2015-12-30 22:35:00.0
1 2 2015-12-30 22:40:00.0
1 2 2015-12-30 23:40:00.0
3 5 2015-11-30 13:40:00.0
3 5 2015-11-30 13:44:00.0
3 5 2015-11-30 19:54:00.0
```

I want

```
dfO:
X Y count
1 2   3
3 5   2
```

In order to count the all the trips from `X` to `Y` I did:

```
tmp = df.groupby(["X", "Y"]).size()
```

How can I take in consideration also the fact that I want to count only the same trips in a certain time interval `dt`?

Comment: use pd.diff on your T column, after the groupby. In that way you'll get the difference with the next trip. Then select on the dt part

Comment: I do not have a T column after the groubpy

Comment: make a new function, with an argument `dt`. In there, do the diff (on T, that should be there) and select only the diff_T == dt parts, return the selected dataframe. then do something like `df.groupby(["X", "Y"]).apply(func)`

Comment: @emax, it's not quite clear how to connect your desired output and `to count trips between X and Y in a certain time windows, let say 15 min`? Can you post desired output?

Comment: How about you do all filtering of data before you do group by ?

Comment: @Sampath I will filter the data before the groupby.

Comment: @MaxU I tried to explain the output: it should count the same trips X-Y between a certain time interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`pd.TimeGrouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#resampling). It allows you to group rows in a DataFrame by intervals of time, provided that the DataFrame has a DatetimeIndex. (Note that [MaxU's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36915955/190597) shows how to group by time intervals without using a DatetimeIndex.)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'T': ['2015-12-30 22:30:00.0',
                         '2015-12-30 22:35:00.0',
                         '2015-12-30 22:40:00.0',
                         '2015-12-30 23:40:00.0',
                         '2015-11-30 13:40:00.0',
                         '2015-11-30 13:44:00.0',
                         '2015-11-30 19:54:00.0'],
                   'X': [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3],
                   'Y': [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]})
df['T'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'])
df = df.set_index(['T'])
result = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('15Min'), 'X', 'Y']).size()
print(result)
```

yields

```
T                    X  Y
2015-11-30 13:30:00  3  5    2
2015-11-30 19:45:00  3  5    1
2015-12-30 22:30:00  1  2    3
2015-12-30 23:30:00  1  2    1
```

This contains the information that you want

```
T                    X  Y
2015-11-30 13:30:00  3  5    2
2015-12-30 22:30:00  1  2    3
```

and more. It is unclear on what basis you wish to exclude the other rows. If you
explain the criterion, we should be able to produce the desired DataFrame exactly.

Comment: @MaxU: I like your answer a bit better than mine. Would you undelete yours so I can delete mine?

Comment: sure, but please don't delete yours ;) and i swear i didn't see yours when i was writing mine :)

Comment: It is exactly what I want but it gives me this error  `TypeError: axis must be a DatetimeIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: @emax: It sounds like your `T` column contains date *strings*. They need to be converted to datetime-like values: `df['T'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'])` or else `pd.TimeGrouper` will not recognize the values as datetimes (or timestamps).

Answer (score 2):

if i understood it correctly:

```
In [34]: df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='T', freq='15min'),'X','Y'], as_index=False).size()
Out[34]:
T                    X  Y
2015-11-30 13:30:00  3  5    2
2015-11-30 19:45:00  3  5    1
2015-12-30 22:30:00  1  2    3
2015-12-30 23:30:00  1  2    1
```